# Hyperref adds vertical space to listings

Tags: spacing, hyperref, listings

When I input a listing with `\lstinputlisting` from the `listings` package, I get an additional vertical space, when I use this in combination with the `hyperref` package. As the picture shows, a certain amount of space is added to the listing.

The output is:
[image]

And the code for this is:

*MWE without hyperref:*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.temp}
Line of code
\end{filecontents*}

Without hyperref:

\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\lstinputlisting[nolol]{\jobname.temp}}

\end{document}
```

*MWE with hyperref:*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.temp}
Line of code
\end{filecontents*}

With hyperref:

\fboxsep=0pt\fbox{\lstinputlisting[nolol]{\jobname.temp}}

\end{document}
```

I played around a lot with settings and even altering the `listings` package code a bit, but I was'nt able to figure out how to get rid of this space. I want the same output, if `hyperref` is loaded or not using the same source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `hyperref` has to put the anchors (link targets) somewhere. The inserted whatsit nodes cannot be made entirely invisible.

At least there is a workaround for this case. It moves the destination setting outside the `\fbox` in vertical mode before. Then it disables the caption stuff of `listings`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.temp}
Line of code
\end{filecontents*}

With hyperref:

\begingroup
  \makeatletter
  \lst@HRefStepCounter{lstlisting}%
  \let\lst@MakeCaption\@gobble
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%
  \fbox{%
    \lstinputlisting[nolol]{\jobname.temp}%
  }%
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I was playing around before with somehow deactivating `\lst@MakeCaption` but I always got errors with a real-world example. As far as I can see now, your code runs perfectly without any error for a huge example file! Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek - the way I see he is just using a simple example for a much larger problem -- that is -- the layout changes up loading hyperrref even if you do NOT use it. Of course, one cannot chase the problems one by one, so what is the correct paradigm to follow when you want to produce a file for screen and print (links and no links) from the same sources?

Comment: @PauloNey There is not "the correct paradigm", there are many, many of more or less correct ways.

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek Would you care to describe them to us? Probably expanding the answer, since this question is extremely important. I would like to understand "why" is it necessary for Hyperref to change the layout, and then how to avoid it on a dual-production system.

Comment: @PauloNey Please, reread the answer, the first paragraph already gives hints for the "why". A full comprehensive answer would require an understanding of TeX's paragraph builder, TeX's page breaking, whatsits (e.g. `\special`), how the hyper features can be implemented with the different drivers, ... This would fill several chapters of a book. A comment is the wrong place for this. A best way to proceed depends very much on the circumstances (one document vs. two documents, features used, TeX expertise, ...).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, I have read a lot -- there are several reports of this problem on SX -- and I believe I do understand well the nature of the problem now. I have seen some mentioning of

     \usepackage[options]{nohyperref}

but have not been able to locate any manual on it, let alone the options....

The specific case I am interested is several hundred legacy manuscripts that need to be produced, with links and without them, and with a fidelity between electronic and paper.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Are there any general solutions that would apply to this case? I am even considering coloring the links blank for the Print version and leaving them there, but it seems a kludge o me ...