# Hyperref adds vertical space to equation environment

Tags: spacing, hyperref, equations

When the length of the text prior to an `equation` environment approaches `\textwidth`, `hyperref` adds an extra vertical space, as illustrated by the following snapshot:

[image]

The corresponding code is

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{a4}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\textwidth = 16cm
\setlength{\parskip}{1.5ex plus0.5ex minus0.5ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\begin{document}
Suppose $\vec{T}$ is a lower triangular matrix. Then $\vec{T}^{T}$ is upper triangular. By Lemma 2.23921,
\begin{equation}
    \det(\vec{T}) = \det(\vec{T}^{T}) = [\vec{T}]_{11}[\vec{T}]_{22}\dotsb[\vec{T}]_{nn},
\end{equation}
as required.
\end{document}
```

Note that it seems to affect the `equation` environment only.

Since there is no apparent way to predetermine the occurrence the problem in the source code,  I will have to manually scan the output text for the affected parts and replace `equation` with other math environments, such as `gather`, to circumvent the problem; clearly, this approach is suboptimal.

So, the question is, why does it only affect the `equation` environment but not other math environments? Is there a way fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: That does not get you A4 paper, by the way. Add `a4paper` to the class options and remove the `a4` package. Also, better to use `\usepackage[textwidth=16cm]{geometry}` to set layout dimensions.

Comment: not in a position to explore the code, but i do know that the `equation` environment is not defined the same way as that of the other `amsmath` enviroments.  it was originally, but there were too many cries from users who wanted to be able to use a "shorthand" form `\be ... \ee` that it was reverted to the original latex (2.09) definition.

Comment: Is the spacing issue similar to the one mentioned [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124986/hyperref-adds-vertical-space-to-listings?rq=1)? Does `hyperref` add anchors for `equation` but not the other maths environments? If you aren't using the anchors, you can load `amsmath` after `hyperref` to avoid the problem, I think. (From another question which I've currently lost track of.)

Comment: @cfr Switching the load order didn't work. Thanks for the heads up by the way. It looks like my template is way too outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're being unlucky, but also `hyperref` should do better.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{equation}{%
  \ifhmode\unskip\fi
}

\textwidth = 16cm
\setlength{\parskip}{1.5ex plus0.5ex minus0.5ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\begin{document}

Suppose $\vec{T}$ is a lower triangular matrix. Then $\vec{T}^{T}$ is upper
triangular. By Lemma 2.23921,
\begin{equation}
    \det(\vec{T}) = \det(\vec{T}^{T}) = [\vec{T}]_{11}[\vec{T}]_{22}\dotsb[\vec{T}]_{nn},
\end{equation}
as required.

\end{document}
```

[image]

<sub>**Note.** I left your setting of `\parindent` and `\parskip`, but this doesn't mean I endorse them. To the contrary, I advice you *not* to use those settings.</sub>

Comment: ...a duplicate of [`fleqn` option and long text lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122343/5764).

Comment: @egreg Thank you for the simple and yet effective solution. Also, I appreciate your advice regarding my layout settings. I have since opted for `\usepackage{parskip}` to have the style of having no indentation with space between paragraphs. It makes me wonder if it is possible to have my 300+ lines of preamble corrected.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that **this is a bug in the `hyperref` package**. When `hyperref` isn't loaded then the paragraph-part before display is ended by a space (after the comma at the end of the line in your excellent example) and then the `\begin{equation}` does `\refstepcounter {equation}` and then it expands to `$$` which starts the display mode. The start of display mode executes TeX internal algorithm: it finalizes the current horizontal mode by `\unskip` (i.e. the mentioned space is removed) and does something similar like `\par` (i.e. the horizontal list is broken to the lines, horizontal mode is interrupted and the lines are contributed to the vertical list). Then the display math is typeset. Note, that this case (without the ending space in the horizontal mode, because it is removed) fits the paragraph-part exactly to one line.

When `hyperref` is loaded, it re-defines the `\refstepcounter` macro. Now, this macro advances the counter by one plus puts the hyperlink destination to the current mode. This current mode is horizontal mode and the destination is put *after* the mentioned space. This destination is realized by `\penalty10000\hbox{...\pdfdest{...}}` but this isn't important. The main result is that the internal `\unskip` action processed when display math is started *cannot remove the mentioned space* because there is a barrier in the form of hyperlink destination. And the horizontal mode is longer by the mentioned space in this case. Now, this horizontal list is broken to the two lines (the second line is empty) and after that, the display math is typeset.