# extra vertical space before equation when using hyperref and fleqn

Tags: hyperref

When using both hyperref and fleqn, I am getting some extra vertical space above numbered equations.  This issue is I believe a known bug in hyperref and has already been discussed at

- [fleqn document class option, long text lines, and hyperref package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122343/fleqn-document-class-option-long-text-lines-and-hyperref-package)
- [Hyperref adds vertical space to equation environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235799/hyperref-adds-vertical-space-to-equation-environment)

but I have not been able to successfully apply the workarounds given there to my specific problem, and that is what I could use some help with.  Here's a MnWE:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\question}[4]{
    \par \noindent \textbf{\ignorespaces#2}
    \nopagebreak[2]
    \vspace{10pt}
    \par \noindent \ignorespaces#3 \textit{\ignorespaces#4}
    \vspace{20pt}
}

\begin{document}

\question{default}{
  A question whose answer is an equation*.
}{
  \begin{equation*} \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \end{equation*}
}{}

\question{default}{
  A question whose answer is an equation.
}{
  \begin{equation} \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \end{equation}
}{}


\question{default}{
  A question whose answer is plain old text.
}{
  The answer.
}{}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

**Some Background**

I have a collection of notes in question-answer format.  I like to review them by covering the (printed) notes with a sheet of paper and moving that paper down until I can see only the question.  At this point I try to remember the answer, and I once I think I've got it, I move the sheet down further to reveal the answer.

Until recently the tex file containing this was something of a mess, so I decided to try writing the macro you see above.  If my macro is completely wrong, let me know and I'll open a separate question on how to do that properly.

Comment: If you intend to always include some sort of display environment in #3, you can set \aboveskipayskip and \belowdisplayskip (temporarily) to the desired values.  If not, you should set them to 0pt.

Answer (score 2):

You should never have a paragraph break before a displayed equation, TeX always does the wrong thing in such a situation. Here I removed the spurious par, also added some missing `%` I left in the `\noindent` although in almost all cases that shouldn't be used in latex,

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\question}[4]{%
    \par \noindent\nopagebreak[2]\textbf{\ignorespaces#2}%
    \ignorespaces#3 \textit{\ignorespaces#4}%
    \vspace{20pt}%
}

\begin{document}

\question{default}{
  My question
}{
  \begin{equation*} \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \end{equation*}
}{}

\question{default}{
  My question
}{
  \begin{equation} \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \end{equation}
}{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately the third argument is sometimes an equation but usually not, and I want the third argument to always go on its own line.  I'll go back and describe the bigger picture in my question.

Comment: What is the purpose of the %'s?  I know that double newlines will start a new paragraph, but I thought a single newline is basically the same as a space.

Comment: @user471651 exactly and you don't want spaces there http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines