# Hyperref inserts vertical space in tabular cell

Tags: tables, spacing, hyperref

I am placing a label inside a cell in a tabular environment, with the "p" column type.  If hyperref is included the cell contains unwanted vertical space messing up the formatting.  Without hyperref, the format is correct.

I am guessing this is related to the problem described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124986/hyperref-adds-vertical-space-to-listings) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122343/fleqn-document-class-option-long-text-lines-and-hyperref-package) but I am unable to adapt the solutions to those questions to my situation.  How do I obtain the correct spacing without ditching hyperref?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{foo}
\renewcommand{\thefoo}{T\arabic{foo}}
\newcommand{\foofoo}{\refstepcounter{foo}\textbf{\thefoo}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{5mm}|p{80mm}|} \hline
\foofoo\label{foo:jeez} & Jeez \\\hline
& Words words wordsWords words wordsWords words words\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

With hyperref:

[image]

Without hyperref:

[image]

(The code for the second example is as above, but with hyperref commented out.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The vertical reference position of a cell with column type `p` is the reference position of the top most element in the cell, e.g.:

- baseline of the top most row,
- baseline of the top most rule,
- above a vertical space,
- the position of a whatsit (\label, `\special`, `\write`, ...)

`\refstepcounter` also creates an anchor with `hyperref`. This is internally implemented by whatsits (e.g. `\special`). Therefore, this anchor whatsit is aligned with the baseline of the next cell's top line.

In principle, you do not want the anchor in the row. At this time, it is unknown, which heights the next cells will have (there could be a large image,
...). It is better to put the anchor out of alignment right *before* the row starts. This can be achieved with `\noalign` before a new row starts:

```
\noalign{\refstepcounter{foo}}
```

However, this also constitutes a group, the internal commands, `\label` relies on, are lost afterwards. Therefore, the `\label` also has to go at this place.
And the `\label` also creates a whatsit, a write request to the `.aux` file.

```
\noalign{\refstepcounter{foo}\label{foo:jeez}}
\textbf{\thefoo}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\newcounter{foo}
\renewcommand{\thefoo}{T\arabic{foo}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{5mm}p{80mm}}
\toprule
\noalign{\refstepcounter{foo}\label{foo:jeez}}
\textbf{\thefoo}
& Jeez \\
& Words words wordsWords words wordsWords words words\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\medskip
Link to \ref{foo:jeez}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Add something to start the paragraph, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{foo}
\renewcommand{\thefoo}{T\arabic{foo}}
\newcommand{\foofoo}{\leavevmode\refstepcounter{foo}\textbf{\thefoo}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{5mm}|p{80mm}|} \hline
\foofoo\label{foo:jeez} & Jeez \\\hline
& Words words wordsWords words wordsWords words words\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```